# How to query mongodb with embedded document

Tags: mongodb

Hi i'm practicing mongodb and I'm stuck with a problem. I'av the following set of documents.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57cf9a134607674792dbad9e"),
    "address" : {
        "building" : "351",
        "coord" : [ 
            -73.9851356, 
            40.7676919
        ],
        "street" : "West   57 Street",
        "zipcode" : "10019"
    },
    "borough" : "Manhattan",
    "cuisine" : "Irish",
    "grades" : [ 
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2014-09-06T00:00:00.000Z"),
            "grade" : "A",
            "score" : 2
        }, 
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2013-07-22T00:00:00.000Z"),
            "grade" : "A",
            "score" : 11
        }, 
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2012-07-31T00:00:00.000Z"),
            "grade" : "A",
            "score" : 12
        }, 
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2011-12-29T00:00:00.000Z"),
            "grade" : "A",
            "score" : 12
        }
    ],
    "name" : "Dj Reynolds Pub And Restaurant",
    "restaurant_id" : "30191841"
}
```

I want to fetch list of all documents where zipcode is 10019
I'm following mongodb db tutorials and i've tried the following queries but nothing seems to work and i'm getting zero errors.

```
 db.restaurants.find({address:{zipcode:10019}});
    db.restaurants.find({"address.zipcode":10019})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`zipcode` is a string so your query should be

```
db.restaurants.find({ "address.zipcode": "10019" })
```

instead of

```
db.restaurants.find({ "address.zipcode": 10019 })
```